# SSL certificate behind AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I have a project running on AWS.
The structure is this:

```
Application Load Balancer:
    - EC2 AutoScaling Group [1-5]:
      - 1^ instance...
      ... (more spawned when needed)
      - 5^ instance...
```

I have created a certificate for the Load Balancer with AWS Certificate Manager. So the traffic now is:

```
Clients ---- HTTPS Port 443 ----- > Load Balancer ------ HTTP Port 80 ----> EC2 Instances
```

But since there is no certificate on the instances when I load the webpage I get a 'Site Not Secure' warning.

How can I create a complete SSL connection from Clients to any of my instances behind the Load Balancer?

**EDIT**

Here is the nginx configuration (for all instances)

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  marette.ovh www.marette.ovh;

root /home/marette/marette_backend/dist;
index index.html index.htm;

client_max_body_size 10M;
error_page 502 /gateway.html;


location / {
   
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*" always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
   
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 30s;
    proxy_send_timeout 30s;

    root /home/marette/marette_backend/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/vue-app-error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/vue-app-access.log;


# this is for the REST backend
location /api {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*" always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
                        # required to be able to read Authorization header in frontend
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization' always;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout 30s;
    proxy_send_timeout 30s;      
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000/api;
   }

}
```

And here is the configuration of the listeners for the Balancer
[image]

**EDIT2**:
[image]

**EDIT3**:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the reason for a warning. Your client is connected to the load balancer via SSL so the connection from the client's perspective is secure. What happens behind the scenes is invisible to the client and doesn't matter. Can you elaborate on that warning please?

Comment: If you could expand on your setup (include screenshots of listeners) then I'll take a look :)

Comment: Maybe the webserver on your instances is misconfigured and doesn't recognize the connection as using the HTTPS protocol (possibly it is not set up to recognize the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header from the load balancer) and redirects the user to URLs with just the HTTP protocol... (or maybe you are connecting via HTTP in the first place and didn't set up a redirect to HTTPS)

Comment: I have edited the main topic with additional informations.

Comment: How does the target group configuration look?

Comment: Just added @ChrisWilliams

Comment: OK can you confirm the SSL loaded on the load balancer is for the domain you're loading?

Comment: See EDIT3 @ChrisWilliams

Comment: That domain does not appear to be connectable. Can you confirm the domain you're loading in the browser? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217445/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-marco-lagalla).

Answer (score 0):

Checks that should be performed:

- Always check the domain name is correct for the SSL, if it is not valid then you will get certificate errors.
- Validate the listener is correctly configured to listen on 443 using HTTPS, and that the SSL is valid.
- Validate the target group is using the correct protocol and port for the server itself (does not need to be the same as the load balancer).

A great site to test for SSL problems is using [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/)